# running a jar file in PHP

Tags: php, wampserver

I have a command to be run like this

```
$command="java -jar ".dirname(__FILE__)."\gmksplit.jar"." ".$input_path." ".$output_path;
```

I have echoed the $command variable and I get the output as

```
java -jar X:\wamp\www\moodle\gmksplit.jar X:\wamp\www\moodle/upload/maze_4.gmk X:\wamp\www\moodle/outputs/maze_4;
```

which is exactly I want to run..
I am trying to run it as

```
echo $exec($command);
```

it is not running. I have tried all the functions like shell_exec() and system()

It gives the output as

```
Java Version: 10700 (1.7.0_01)
```

when i run the same line in command prompt I get the output as

```
Java Version: 10700 (1.7.0_01)
Loading lib files in X:\wamp\www\moodle\gmksplit.jar
01_move.lgl 02_main1.lgl 03_main2.lgl 04_control.lgl
 05_score.lgl 06_extra.lgl 07_draw.lgl
time taken to load file: 254 ms
```

so, as you see my php code is giving only the first line as output. The command is not running properly and I am not getting the intended output.

please help  me

I am using the wampp server

Comment: [From PHP: exec - Manual in the comments section][1]

Sounds like you may need elevated privileged to accomplish what you want.

> - execute services.msc and find the apache service (In my case wampapache)
> - Right button>Log On tab and change from Local System Account to a user created account, enter the username and the password and restart
> the service.


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

```
<?php
$command="java -jar ".dirname(__FILE__)."\gmksplit.jar"." ".$input_path." ".$output_path;
$out = array();
exec = ($command, $out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried it
I am getting the same output as
Array ( [0] => Java Version: 10700 (1.7.0_01) )